# How can I turn off mandatory transactions in Neo4j 2.0?

Tags: neo4j

How can I turn off mandatory transactions in Neo4j 2.0? I need to do this as the library I am using does not support the 2.0 transactional API yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've said, in Neo4j 2.0 transactions are mandatory and there is no way to switch this off. If you're relying on Cypher be aware that the Cypher's ExecutionEngine automatically opens and closes a transaction if there is no one available from outside.

Depending on your environment and architecture you can use cross-cutting concerns to manage transactions separately from your code base. Think of java servlet filters, and aspect with aspectj, byte code manipulation, Groovy MOP magic, and other technologies. For a more focussed answer you should give more insight in your project regarding used languages, frameworks and architecture.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to know if there was a switch to turn trnasactions off as I have Neo4j 1.9 code which I will have to rewrite to support transactions now

Answer (score 2):

what if you are running neo4j in read-only mode? and you are more interested in speed rather than concurency as there is no race conditions.

from http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-isolation.html there will always be a transaction :/